# <template> replacement for C linked list

Tags: c, templates, linked-list

Just finished small linked list in C, and realized that I got a problem.
There is no template arguments for C, so at the start of the file, I declare my data type for list, something like:

```
typedef int LData;
```

So far so good, but I can't use this linked list for 2 (or more) different data types in one program.

I can define `LData` as `void*` and manually convert it to specific datatype according to context. But I wonder if there are more elegant solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Define your `LData` type as a `void*`. The user of the linked list has to know what sort of data it contains, so they can cast to and from `void*` whenever they're pulling data in or out.

Comment: The casts are unnecessary in C.

Answer (score 1):

The `union` was invented for this purpose, although it is not a very safe construct.

Comment: Every construct is only as safe as you let it be.

Comment: Fair enough. C is not for the faint hearted ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Or, use the opaque pointer idiom:

```
struct datum;
typedef struct datum datum;
typedef datum *LData;

struct datum {
   int whatever;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a bunch of #defines defining the type stored in the "link"?

ie.

```
 #define TYPE_INT   0
 #define TYPE_FLOAT 1
 // etc
```

Then define each entry as something like this:

```
 struct LinkedListLink
 {
      int    type;
      LData  data;
 };
```

Now by checking "type" you know what sort of data was added (Provided you set it appropriately when you set up the LinkedListLink struct).

Answer (score 0):

When I want to use a generalized set of linked list (or in my case, queue) code, I embed the linked list pointer inside the larger structure that I want to use it with.  Then use the link field name when passing arguments to the linked list functions.  And have a function that can convert from a linked list pointer to the larger struct pointer for when I get pointers back from my linked list.  Something like the code you see below.

This idiom doesn't give you the type safety of C++, but the code is pretty clean, with the casting is localized into just a few functions.

```
// some representative bits of my linked list API
//
typedef void* PLINK;

extern PLINK LLAddToList(PLINK head, PLINK new);
extern PLINK LLNextItem(PLINK current); 

// the structure I want to use it with

typedef struct _foo {
   PLINK  pLink;
   int    data1; 
   int    data2;
} FOO;

// to allow for the link pointers to be some other than the first field
// we use this to go from link pointer to structure pointer.
FOO * FooFromPLink(PLINK current) {
    return (FOO *)((char *)&current - FIELD_OFFSET(FOO, pLink));
}

void MyFunction()
{
   // this idiom to use the linklist code with a FOO struct
   //
   FOO * pfoo = // allocate and initialize a foo
   LLAddToList(head, &pfoo->pLink);


   // this idiom to traverse a list of FOOs, etc.
   //
   PLINK next = LLNextItem(head);
   while (next)
      {
      pfoo = FooFromPLink(next);
      // operate on foo.
      next = LLNextItem(next);
      }

}
```